# Problems with Windows 7 and HD

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, ssd

I have an Intel i5, Windows 7 Ultimate, an SSD as my main drive and 2 SATA hard drives.

One day I got a BSOD and my PC restarted. After that the following error appeared:

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  Status: 0xc000000e

  Info: The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible.
```

I also noticed that BIOS only detected one of the hard drives, not the SSD or the other hard drive.

Sometimes Windows can be started, but it doesn't work very well. When trying to copy data from F: to an external USB, it copies for a short time and then Windows 7 becomes unresponsive. This also happens in safe mode.

After several reboots, now Windows will not boot and I get the error: `The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible.` And the BIOS only detects the SSD.

My disks:
 HDD: WDC WD10EARS-22Y5B1
 HDD: Seagate ST31000528AS
 SSD: FM-25S2S-120GBP2 - G.SKILL

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has posted a possible solution at 
[Use the Bootrec.exe tool in the Windows Recovery Environment to troubleshoot and repair startup issues in Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392)

You can use the Bootrec.exe tool in the Windows Recovery Environment (Windows RE) to troubleshoot and repair the following items in Windows Vista or Windows 7:

- A master boot record (MBR)
- A boot sector
- A Boot Configuration Data (BCD) store

To run the Bootrec.exe tool, you must start Windows RE. To do this, follow these steps:

1. Put the Windows Vista or Windows 7 installation disc in the disc
   drive, and then start the computer.
2. Press a key when you are prompted.
3. Select a language, a time, a currency, a keyboard or an input
   method, and then click Next.
4. Click Repair your computer.
5. Click the operating system that you want to repair, and then click
   Next.
6. In the System Recovery Options dialog box, click Command Prompt.
7. Type Bootrec.exe, and then press ENTER.

Comment: I'll try it. I noticed when Windows 7 is initiated, becomes unresponsive in few time. Disk access not responds.

Comment: I noticed now in BIOS detects only one of HDDs, not SSD neither other HDD.

Comment: Have you moved the machine recently and perhaps dislodged a cable?  I'd open the covers and check that everything is firmly seated.

Comment: I check SATA cable (I connect disks to Channel 0 Master - SSD, and others in Channel 1, 2). If I use Live CD Ubuntu, I dont detect any problem, and I can copy files to USB HD extern. I'm confuse